# I am searching for way to customize Y-Axis in recharts react library?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization, recharts

Yaxis will have custom labels instead of numbers, it is divided into 3 stages and each stage will have 3 levels 1s, 2s, 3s. Please suggest how to customize YAxis using recharts library?

3s
2s
1s
Stage C
3s
2s
1s
Stage B
3s
2s
1s
Stage A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking for something like this:

```js
<YAxis
     tickFormatter={(tick) => {
     return `${tick} and some other label`;
     }}
/>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot webcoder !!! i am able to create labels. But still not able to achieve sub ticks like 1s , 2s 3s.